# Как задать типы, зависимые от других типов? typescript

Tags: typescript

Есть тип данных `Kind`, который может быть 'profit' | 'cost' и есть тип данных `Kinds` - это массив, в нем не может быть два одинаковых значение, либо ['profit', 'cost'] либо ['cost', 'profit'].

Ниже я добился лишь того, чтобы компилятор не ругался, но пока не знаю как описать правильную закономерность.

```
type Kind = 'profit' | 'cost';
type Kinds = [Kind, Kind];

const kinds: { give: Kinds; take: Kinds } = {
  give: ['cost', 'profit'],
  take: ['profit', 'cost'],
};

const getKindForLoanOperation = (kind: 'give' | 'take'): Kinds => kinds[kind];
```

Comment: то что вы хотите, это не задача типов. Вы хотите проверять уже значения, а не сами типы, и `ts` тут не причем

Comment: А реально значений сколько? Для двух я бы не выпендривался и написал `type Kinds = ['cost', 'profit'] | ['profit' | 'cost'];`